java web to change the data that appear

i want to make the value that showed in my jsp to be the total student that i have in my database.
But it showed null eventhough i have 3 data in there
this what i do:
my DAO:
import com.fyp.connection.MySqlConnection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DashboardLecturerDAO {

    public int getTotalStudentCount() {
        int totalCount = 0;
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            
            connection = new MySqlConnection().getConnection();
            
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM student";
            
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                totalCount = resultSet.getInt("total");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            
            try {
                if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
                if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return totalCount;
    }

}

my servlet:
import com.fyp.model.Dao.lecturer.DashboardLecturerDAO;
import java.io.IOException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "Dashboard_LecturerServlet", urlPatterns = {"/Dashboard_LecturerServlet"})
public class Dashboard_LecturerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        DashboardLecturerDAO dashboardLecturerDAO = new DashboardLecturerDAO();
        
        int totalCount = dashboardLecturerDAO.getTotalStudentCount();
        
        request.setAttribute("totalCount", totalCount);
        
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Dashboard-Lecturer.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        
    }
    
    
    
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}

my connection class:
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySqlConnection {
private String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
private String jdbcUsername = "root";
private String jdbcPassword = "";

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

}

jsp code:
  <p><%= request.getAttribute("totalCount") %></p>
  <p>Total Students</p>


By the way, learn to use try-with-resources syntax for JDBC code. Covered many times on Stack Overflow.

You tagged "servlet-3.0" but you are using jakarta.* package names that exist only in Servlet 5.0 and later.

I cannot pinpoint your problem. So I suggest you clean up your code to make it easier to debug.
The first thing to do is separate your database work from your user-interface face (Servlet & JSP) work.
User-interface
You tagged your Question with "servlet-3.0", yet your imports use the jakarta.* package names found in Servlet 5.0 and later specifications. So for my example here, I used Servlet 6.0 from Jakarta EE 10.
I ran the example code below in IntelliJ 2024.1 Ultimate Edition in conjunction with Tomcat 10.1.23 as an external server. I am building and running on Java 22.
I deleted the web.xml file from my initial project, because it is unnecessary if using the annotations such as @WebServlet.
Our servlet is brief, just stuffing a hard-coded 42 into your attribute totalCount.
package work.basil.example.exservlet6;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;

@WebServlet (name = "DashboardServlet", value = "/dashboard")
public class DashboardServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("TRACE - DashboardServlet at "+ Instant.now() );
        int totalCount =  42 ;
        request.setAttribute("totalCount", totalCount);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Dashboard.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}

Then we forward the request to our JSP.
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><%= request.getAttribute( "totalCount" ) %>
</p>
<p>Total Students</p>

</body>
</html>

Voilà! Our JSP renders with the 42 we passed via attribute.

The lessons to learn here:

Do the absolute minimum of code, test it. Only after that is working do you add another minimum of useful code, test it. And so on.
Separation of Concerns.

Database
As for the database part of your project, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.
I urge you to do some searching in Stack Overflow for examples of how to properly do basic JDBC work. You will find many examples, including some entire example apps posted by me.
Some brief tips:

Learn to use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close your JDBC resources such as Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet.
Make a habit of storing your database connection info (server address, username, password, etc.) in a DataSource object. You should find a database-specific implementation with your JDBC driver.
Learn about the Repository pattern commonly used, defining an interface with operations to store and retrieve from the database, and then a bogus implementation of that interface to get going, and a real implementation for use in production.

If, after thorough searching of Stack Overflow, you have any remaining problems/questions then post another Question on a narrowly-focused specific programming problem.
